# VBA Excel 2016 - Is it possible to import System.Diagnostics to see if a process is open and then switch to it?

Tags: vba, excel, process, system.diagnostics

I am trying to import system.diagnostics into Excel VBA so that I can have it search for an open process, and then switch to it. System is already imported as part of the references, and when I look in the object browser I cannot see the functions that are associated with system.diagnostics such as Process[] , Process.GetProcessesByName(procName); etc.

Is there are way to import system.diagnostics, or a different way to go about finding an open program in Windows and switch to it? Possibly using the shell references instead?

Eventually I'd like the spreadsheet to interact with the program it has found and made active, such as using user32.dll to SwitchToThisWindow(Program.MainWindowHandle, True);  to grab some data and pull it in.

Maybe this is all out of scope of what Excel VBA can do and I should instead build it outside of Excel. I would prefer to do it all in Excel of course.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Typically, this is handled by importing C level function like FindWindow from user32 lib.

Comment: This has been done (and been documented) many times using the user32 functions but I will caution you to ensure that your compiler directives for xl32-bit under win32, xl32-bit under win64 and xl64-bit under win64 are set up correctly from the start.

Comment: Thank you @Jeeped for the advice. I'll dig deeper into user32 and what it has to offer and stop trying to import system.diagnostics.